# Android View.draw(bitmap) saving view to bitmap does not render BlurMaskFilter properly

Tags: android, view, bitmap, draw, blur

I am trying to programmatically create a gray Rect and black Rect with BlurMaskFilter layer (drop shadow effect) by overriding onDraw in a custom View.  I am able to get it to draw on screen without any issues, but when I try to draw the view to a bitmap the results are different.  In drawing to bitmap, it appears BlueMaskFilter is applied to the View rather than the specific layer of the black Rect.

What am I missing to make the drawn bitmap same as the output drawn on screen?

CustomView's onDraw override:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    //  draw black box (shadow) first
    RectF rectShadow = new RectF();
    rectShadow.set(10, 10, 120, 120);
    Paint shadowPaint = new Paint();
    shadowPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(5, Blur.NORMAL));
    shadowPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    shadowPaint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    shadowPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawRect(rectShadow, shadowPaint);
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, shadowPaint);

    // draw grey box
    RectF rectGray = new RectF();
    rectGray.set(0, 0, 100, 100);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#656565"));
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectGray, paint);
}
```

Function to save view to bitmap:

```
public void saveViewToBitmap( View customView int outWidth, int outHeight ) {
    customView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(outWidth, outHeight));
    customView.measure(
        ViewGroup.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(customView.getLayoutParams().width, 
                                              ViewGroup.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        ViewGroup.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(customView.getLayoutParams().height,
                                              ViewGroup.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    customView.layout(0, 0, 
        customView.getMeasuredWidth(), customView.getMeasuredHeight());
    customView.requestLayout();

    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(outWidth, outHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(outputBitmap);
    customView.draw(canvas);

    return outputBitmap;
}
```

Note in the following images the screen image has crisp edges for the gray rect, whereas the drawn bitmap has the top and left edges of the gray rect blurred demonstrating the problem.

Image on screen:https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hl0t.png

Image saved from bitmap created by saveViewToBitmap: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNzi5.png

Thanks!